# Grid View Formatting Asp.net my code Attached

Tags: asp.net, gridview, formatting

as i wanna format my grid view as it is only showing data like this,

```
john
Adam
Morkel
Kalis
.
.
.
```

.

i wanna show them in this way ,

```
john    Kalis   .
                . 
Adam    Chris   .
         .      .
morkel   .      .
```

my code after attaching data sorce,

```
GridView1.DataSource = dt;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

hopes for your Suggestions thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're better off using a [DataList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc295015.aspx) control.

for your multi row/multi column need, take a look at "*Step 3: Displaying Data in a Multi-Column, Multi-Row Table*" at http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/data-access/displaying-data-with-the-datalist-and-repeater/showing-multiple-records-per-row-with-the-datalist-control-vb

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use `DataList` instead of `gridview`

check these examples

http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/data-access/displaying-data-with-the-datalist-and-repeater/displaying-data-with-the-datalist-and-repeater-controls-vb

http://www.packtpub.com/article/working-with-asp-dot-net-datalist-control

**Edit:**

.aspx

```
  <ItemTemplate>
    <ul>
       <li> <%# Container.DataItem %></li>
    </ul>
  </ItemTemplate>

</asp:DataList>
```

.cs

```
 List<string> ss = new List<string>();
    ss.Add("john");
    ss.Add("Adam");
    ss.Add("Morkel");
    ss.Add("Kalis");
    ss.Add("Chris");
    DataList1.DataSource=ss;
    DataList1.DataBind();
```

Comment: Ok its fine but let me know even by using data list and repeater how to move the same record to the next column using these controls any idea ??

Comment: set properties RepeatDirection="Vertical" RepeatColumns="3" in the data list , then make your ItemTemplate in the datalist , and bind your datasource

Comment: here is an example http://dl.dropbox.com/u/44648822/WebForm1.aspx   , http://dl.dropbox.com/u/44648822/WebForm1.aspx.cs